# is there a way to resolve log inequality by hand

Tags: inequality, logarithms

I am wondering if there is a way to resolve the following inequality:
$$n<8\log_2(n)$$

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: I'll try calculus.

Comment: cf. [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sketch should convince you that $n=8\log_2(n)$ has two positive solutions which you could find using the Lambert W function or numerical methods. Since $8\log_2(n)-n$ is continuous, it is easy to see that one is between $1$ and $2$ and the other between $32$ and $64$

If you are looking for integer solutions to the inequality, you could just test the integers up to $64$; you want $n^8-2^n$ to be positive

Otherwise, find the solutions to the equality and you could test the inequality with $n=1,2,64$ to see which interval(s) you want for the inequality

Comment: Ok so this is more an empirical methods, isn’t It ?